# Spring Boot JPA Query - It is not possible to filter the associated entity in the one-to-many relationship

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, filtering, one-to-many, lombok

I'm using Spring boot 3.1.6 and Lombok.I want to retrieve all objects (`ObjectA`) where the child entity (`ObjectB`) is filtered based on the value.For example:

if I call `findAll()` in my ObjectARepository i will have this:

ObjectA

```
+------------------------------+
|  id: 1                       |
|  ...                         |
|                              |
|   children:                  |
|   +--------------------+     |
|   |  +--------------+  |     |
|   |  |  id: 101     |  |     |
|   |  |  value: 10   |  |     |
|   |  +--------------+  |     |
|   |  +--------------+  |     |
|   |  |  id: 102     |  |     |
|   |  |  value: 15   |  |     |
|   |  +--------------+  |     |
|   |  +--------------+  |     |
|   |  |  id: 103     |  |     |
|   |  |  value: 25   |  |     |
|   |  +--------------+  |     |
|   +--------------------+     |
+------------------------------+
```

if I call `findByValue(15)` in my ObjectARepository I want to do this (but I have all children):

ObjectA

```
+------------------------------+
|  id: 1                       |
|  ...                         |
|                              |
|   children:                  |
|   +--------------------+     |
|   |  +--------------+  |     |
|   |  |  id: 102     |  |     |
|   |  |  value: 15   |  |     |
|   |  +--------------+  |     |
|   +--------------------+     |
+------------------------------+
```

My code ------

ObjectA entity:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "OBJECT_A")
public class ObjectAEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_object_a")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "creation_time", nullable = false)
    private Date creationTime;

    @Column(name = "execution_id", nullable = false)
    private String executionId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "object", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ObjectBEntity> children;

    @PrePersist
    private void onCreate() {
        if (this.creationTime == null) {
            this.creationTime = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
        }
    }

    // equals and hashCode
}
```

ObjectB entity:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "OBJECT_B")
public class ObjectBEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_object_b")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
    private Double value;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_objects_a")
    private ObjectAEntity object;

    // equals and hashCode

}
```

ObjectA repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ObjectARepository extends JpaRepository<ObjectAEntity, Integer> {
    
    @Query("select o from ObjectAEntity o inner join o.children children where children.value = :value")
    List<ObjectAEntity> findByChildren_Value(@Param("value") @NonNull Double value);
}
```

I have attempted various approaches, including left join, left join fetch, inner join, inner join fetch, along with subqueries, entity graph, and different combinations of EAGER and LAZY fetching. However, all the methods I've tried yield the same outcome – all child entities are fetched instead of being properly filtered.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to properly achieve the desired result. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just took your code, added "fetch" to the query and it works, exactly like you want. Are you sure you tried it? If yes, can you enable "show-sql" setting and share what SQL query Hibernate makes in this case?